# Python crop image in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

Is there any way to crop image from top, bottom, left, right side by detecting first pixel from each side where alpha is not 0? I have image loaded in numpy array in this format.

Thank you so much for your answers!

```
 [[[105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  ...
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]]

 [[105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  ...
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]]

 [[105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  ...
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]]
  ...

 [[105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  ...
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]
  [105 105 105   0]]]
```

Comment: Kindly provide the image and your current best-effort code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code from a [similar thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132934) to work with your requirements:

```py
def crop_image_outside_based_on_transparency(img, tol=0):
    # img is 3D image data with transparency channel
    # tol is tolerance (0 in your case)
    # we are interested only in the transparency layer so:
    trans_layer = img[:,:,3]
    mask = trans_layer > tol
    m, n = trans_layer.shape
    mask0, mask1 = mask.any(0), mask.any(1)
    col_start,col_end = mask0.argmax(),n-mask0[::-1].argmax()
    row_start,row_end = mask1.argmax(),m-mask1[::-1].argmax()
    return img[row_start:row_end, col_start:col_end, :]
```

Note for a future: please provide example data so it's easier for us to work on a solution

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Next time I will provide more info, I am sorry but I am new contributor on this portal and I don't know stuff here. Have a nice day and thank you!

Comment: No problem - welcome to the community! :) would be great if you could mark my post as the correct answer if it works for you, thanks!